# Is it safe to use `for(auto& e : cont)`? What is wrong with vector<bool>?

Tags: c++, c++11, boolean, stdvector, auto

I have found that `for (auto& e : cont)` is sometimes used instead of ordinary `for (auto e : cont)` (where `cont` is some container, e.g. `std::vector`). I have found two reasons for it so far:

1. Taking a reference should avoid copying the object (faster execution)
2. Making a copy may be forbidden for some classes (e.g. `std::thread`)

After few tests I can see:

1. `for (auto& e : cont)` works with any `std::vector<T>` except `std::vector<bool>`
2. *`for (cont::reference e : cont)`* works with any `std::vector<T>` **including `std::vector<bool>`** (the obvious question here is:
   **Should I rather use this instead of `for (auto& e : cont)`?**
3. `std::vector<bool>` is not considered to be real container and many think that it should be renamed (the implementation is fine and usefull, but should have different name like `bitset` or `bitfield` or `dynamic_bitset`)
4. `std::vector<bool>` can be implemented in a way that `for (auto& e : cont)` would work as well (see my attempts below)

***Here is the code I have used for testing:***
(the trick is to use `reference& iterator::operator * () { return *this; }`)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

#define USE_STD_VECT_BOOL 0

#if USE_STD_VECT_BOOL
typedef vector<bool> BITS;
#else
typedef class bvect {
    unsigned data; // we could use vector<unsigned> but this is just an examle
    unsigned size;
public:
    bvect(): data(0), size(0) {}
    void push_back(bool value) {
        if(value) data |= (1u<<size);
        size++; }
    class reference {
        friend class bvect;
    protected:
        unsigned& data;
        unsigned  flag;
        reference(unsigned& data, unsigned flag)
        : data(data), flag(flag) {}
    public:
        operator bool() const {
            return data & flag; }
        reference& operator = (bool value) {
            if(value) data |= flag;
            else data &= ~flag;
            return *this; }
    };
    class iterator: protected reference  {
        friend class bvect;
        iterator(unsigned& data, unsigned flag)
        : reference(data, flag) {}
    public:
        typedef bool value_type;
        typedef bvect::reference reference;
        typedef input_iterator_tag iterator_category;
    //  HERE IS THE TRICK:
        reference& operator * () {
            return *this; }
        iterator& operator ++ () {
            flag <<= 1;
            return *this; }
        iterator operator ++ (int) {
            iterator tmp(*this);
            operator ++ ();
            return tmp; }
        bool operator == (const iterator& rhs) {
            return flag == rhs.flag; }
        bool operator != (const iterator& rhs) {
            return flag != rhs.flag; }
    };
    iterator begin() {
        return iterator(data, 1); }
    iterator end() {
        return iterator(data, 1<<size); }
} BITS;
#endif

int main() {
    BITS bits;
    bits.push_back(0);
    bits.push_back(1);
#if !USE_STD_VECT_BOOL
//  won't compile for vector<bool>
    for(auto& a : bits)
        cout << typeid(a).name()
          << " = " << (int)(bool)a
          << endl;
#endif
//  std::_Bit_Reference
    for(BITS::reference a : bits)
        cout << typeid(a).name()
          << " = " << (int)(bool)a
          << endl;
//  few more tests
    for(auto a : bits)
        cout << (int)(bool)a;
    for(bool a : bits)
        cout << (int)(bool)a;
    cout << endl;
}
```

***Questions:***

1. Should I rather use `for (cont::reference e : cont)` instead of `for (auto& e : cont)`?
2. What is wrong with the trick? Can it be enhanced to be fine for any use-case?
   **EDIT: I am refering to `bvect::reference& bvect::iterator::operator * () { return *this; }` here.**
3. Can/Should STL be changed? (refering to `vector<bool>`)

***FEEDBACK: Answers and Comments:***

1. Using `for (auto&& e : cont)` (for writing) or `for (const auto& e : cont)` (for reading/enumerating) seems to work in all cases. (Thanks go to dyp and Praetorian)
2. Using `typename iterator_traits<decltype(begin(cont))>::reference` seems to work even for arrays (cont=boo[2]). (Yes, it is ugly but could be shortened using some template alias I think. I cannot think of counter-example where this would be needed, so, for now, this is not the solution. `auto&&` is)
3. Standard says that `iterator::operator * ()` have to return `iterator::reference` (not `iterator::reference&`), but still no clue why.

***Final Verdict:***

```
auto it = bits.begin();
auto&& e = *it; cout << (bool)e;
it++; cout << (bool)e;
cout << endl;
```

Output:

```
10
```

This is definitely bad. We should stick with the standard (`iterator::operator * ()` have to return `iterator::reference`). *Thank you :)*

Comment: A guideline you often hear is: either `auto&&` or `auto const&`, depending on whether or not you want to modify the elements.

Comment: `for (cont::reference e : cont)` obviously doesn't work with C-style arrays.

Comment: `typename iterator_traits<It>::reference r = *i; ++i; r = *i;` will have strange behaviour with this iterator. I'm not sure if it fulfills all mutable RAIt requirements.

Comment: Not sure if your trick is UB, as you take the reference of a hidden temporary...

Comment: @dyp: r = *i makes a copy (iterator_traits<bvect::iterator>::reference = bvect::reference, r = *i should call copy constructor), ++i advances the iterator (no change to r), r = *i takes another copy. What is wrong?

Comment: @Jarod42: Hidden temporary? It is simple casting of the iterator which is something you already have. The only way to exploit it I can think of is this: `bvect::reference& the_ref = *bits.begin()` but such code does not make any sense.

Comment: @firda In that case, you're violating the requirement that `*i` shall return a `reference`, not a `reference&`.

Comment: @dyp: where is such thing specified? [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) I can read that `*i` should/must be *convertible* to value_type (nothing else).

Comment: @firda Table 106 / [iterator.iterators] in the Standard or later drafts. On cppreference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator These requirements are "inherited" from `Iterator` to `InputIterator`.

Comment: @dyp: OK, standard states, we should follow. Can you point me to some reasoning why it was standardized like that? I still don't understand why it is wrong (why it could be so dangerous).

Comment: Hmm. I can't really see what could go wrong in an algorithm, but that of course doesn't mean that there isn't a corner-case where it could go wrong. Someone could `static_assert` that `*i` returns a `reference`; overload resolution could fail / select a wrong overload, etc.

Comment: I'd like to understand it. Don't see a point in such static_assert (like 'do you follow standard or not? if not then go away'). BTW: this works for arrays: `typename iterator_traits<decltype(begin(bits))>::reference` (I was just searching how all that works - iterator_traits are defined for pointers but not for arrays, using `decltype(begin(bits))` can pass that (when bits = bool[2]). `for (auto&& e : c)` seems fine.

Comment: Such a `static_assert` can occur in heavily templated code not as a security measure, but to improve error messages (à la Concepts). Overload resolution is still the best answer I can come up with, but I doubt that's the rationale. Maybe the requirements are just too strict.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I wanted to undrstand all that not to make any bad mistake while writing templates with proxy classes (like `_Bit_reference` for `vectotr<bool>` or whatever proxy for set/map-like `operator[]`). Thx again.

Comment: @firda: By hidden temporary, I meant hidden variable. You use implicitly `iterator::operator *` in the for range, I'm not sure of the lifetime of this hidden iterator.

Comment: @Jarod42: ranged for-loop is not a problem (because iteration expression is evaluated at the end), but explicit iterator usage involving `auto&&` is a problem (see my Final Verdict added on my question). `auto&& e = *it++` is the problematic pattern (getting reference& by universal reference, changing the iterator and then accessing the captured reference - state changed as it is linked with the iterator).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`vector<bool>` is a specialization of the `vector` class template that stores the booleans in a bitfield for space optimization. Since you cannot return a reference to a bitfield, `vector<bool>::reference` is a class type, a proxy that represents a single `bool`. `vector<bool>::operator[]` returns this proxy class instance by value; the same applies to dereferencing a `vector<bool>::iterator`.

```
vector<bool> cont;
for (auto& e : cont) { ... }
```

Here you're attempting to bind an lvalue reference to an rvalue, which is not allowed.

> Should I rather use `for (cont::reference e : cont)` instead of `for (auto& e : cont)`?
>   What is wrong with the trick? Can it be enhanced to be fine for any use-case?

The nice thing about a range-based for is that it works for a plain C array too. Using `cont::reference` will fail for those, as well as any iterable type that doesn't have a member type named `reference`. You should use `for(auto const& e : cont)` if you want read only access to the container elements within the loop, and `for(auto&& e : cont)` if you want to modify the elements.

In the latter case, `auto&& e` is a *universal reference* that can bind to lvalues and rvalues, so it works in the `vector<bool>` case too.

Comment: This answers the first question (dyp did that in comments alread). Thank you for the explanation. I am willing to accept this answer because it renders my bvect attempt as useless, but still... What about the second question? What is wrong with my trick?

Comment: @firda It's explained in the second half. Using `cont::reference` won't work if you're iterating over a plain C array, so it cannot be extended for all use cases.

Comment: 1. `typename iterator_traits<decltype(begin(cont))>::reference` works even for `cont=bool[2]` 2. I was refering to the trick = `bvect::iterator operator *()`. (I can see no answer to that, but I can understand that I should improve my question).

Comment: @firda 1. You've gone from `auto&&` to something hideous, with no obvious benefit. 2. As dyp already mentioned in the comments, the iterator requirements state that dereferencing should return a `reference` and not `reference&`. Ignoring that, I don't see anything wrong immediately, but your design seems unclean. Your `iterator` needs to inherit from `reference` to make your trick work.

Comment: 1. See **FEEDBACK** added on my question (yes `auto&&` accepted). 2. Sure, that is the point, it seems that I am violating the standard, but can't see the problem in it. Inheriting iterator from reference is indeed part of the trick (but iterator, pointer and reference have same or similar underlaying structure - so, can't see a problem in this either).

Comment: @firda I'm not sure what kind of answer you're expecting. I don't know the rationale behind the iterator requirements. Violating the standard is never a good idea because there might be code out there that depends on that particular behavior.

Comment: `auto&& e = *it++` looks like a problem, that was the answer I was searching for. Can you confirm that? What if I return `const reference& operator * () { return *this; }`? That would be answer to the other question (can it be enhanced?) what now, can you think of any other problem?

Comment: Ahh, `const reference&` won't bind to `auto&`. I think this is the end.

Answer (score 0):

For space optimization `vector<bool>` uses to store bool value only one bit (instead of one byte like `bool`). You can't get address of a bit in byte, due to things such `operator[]` doesn't work. In your case, you can't iterate bit by bit in this vector. You should better use `set<bool>`. There is a lot of discussion about `vector<bool>` if it should be in `STL`.

Comment: I cannot iterate? I can! Those ranged for-loops prove it. What am I missng? vector<bool>::operator[] is returning a 'proxy object' (_Bit_reference) which emulates reference (same as mine bvect::reference). Did not get your answer (do not understand), sorry.

Comment: + set<bool> does not make sense, it is a set of four possible states (empty, zero, one, both).

Comment: I don't think there is a "a lot of discussion" about whether the `vector<bool>` specialisation should be in the standard. I suspect that back in the day, before the C++98 standard became official, there was not enough discussion, because otherwise the consensus would surely have been that it's a bad thing. Today, everyone has come to accept that it's premature optimisation, but removing it would be unacceptable due to backward compatibility. Again, no discussion :)